# How to add event for dangerousSetHtml?

Tags: reactjs, redux

Ask a React question. I set the data in `dangerSetHtml == {{__ html:data}}`.

The data contains img. I want to bind an new event to img. My solution is .data inside as long as img has an id of `999` I am in function `componentDidmount` to write `document.getElementById('999').addEventListener('click', handler)`

Is `addEventListener('click',handler)` feasible? or is there any better solution?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use `addEventListener` in componentDidMount. But also, make sure to remove the listener on component unmount:

```js
componentWillUnmount() {
  document.getElementById(your_id).removeEventListener('click', handler)
}
```

Comment: Thank you， Have you tested it? I did not respond after clicking.      But I hava a better method to handle it . Bind a event function on a parent div. Monitor by bubbling.